# Calculate Percentile of a group of values if a Date is on a specific month in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, percentile

I'm currently utilizing the following formula to count the records on a data set for the month of april and is working.

=COUNTIFS(RAW_DATA_CT!$D$2:$D$148,"<=04/30/2017",RAW_DATA_CT!$D$2:$D$148,">=04/01/2017")

I would like to use the same logic but instead of counting I would like to calculate the PERCENTILE using the values in another column for those records between that meet that criteria.

Comment: What have you tried? Percentile calculations necessarily require a value, and a set of values to compare to. It's not clear what is your specific value, and what is the set of values to be compared to, or how those values are to be compared. (Note that you should never expect anyone to follow a link to your personal spreadsheet - you should always provide enough context directly in your question)

Comment: I tried already Nested IF for example: =IF({RAW_DATA_CT!$D$2:$D$148} <=4/30/2017 ,IF({RAW_DATA_CT!$D$2:$D$148} >=4/1/2017 ,PERCENTILE({RAW_DATA_CT!$I$2:$I$113},0.5),),0).  I'm only getting FALSE so is returning 0

Comment: Consider using [`=FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)